# Prevent pandas from reading None as Nan

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy, nan

I have cleaned a dataset and had to replace a lot of `NaN` values with `None`. After that I saved it to a new csv file, when I read the cleaned dataset back using `pandas.read_csv`, all the `None` values are represented as `NaN`, how can I avoid this?

Comment: use the na_filter=False in read_csv

Comment: A column with `nan` can have a float dtype.  One with `None` will be object dtype.  Calculation will be slower.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use parameter `keep_default_na` and `na_values` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) strings `None` to values `None`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""a,b
None,NaN
a,8"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp),keep_default_na=False,na_values=['NaN'])

print (df)
      a    b
0  None  NaN
1     a  8.0

print (type(df.a.iloc[0]))
<class 'str'>

df = df.replace({'None':None})
print (df)
      a    b
0  None  NaN
1     a  8.0

print (type(df.a.iloc[0]))
<class 'NoneType'>
```